# How to update data in a collectionview within a tableview?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

Hi right now I have a `UICollectionView` within a `UITableViewCell`. The the `UICollectionView` acts as a place to put tags for each individual cell. It currently displays fine when I'm not searching/filtering the `UITableViewCell`s, but when I am searching, and the code is filtering the `UITableViewCell`s, the `UICollectionView` doesn't filter with it.

Here is what I mean:

How the cells look when it is not filtering (each bullet point is a `UITableViewCell`):

- Title A, description A, [TagA1, TagA2, TagA3]
- Title B, description B, [TagB1]
- Title C, description C, [TagC1, TagC2]

How the cells look when it is filtering:

- Title A, description A, [TagA1, TagA2, TagA3]
- Title C, description C, [TagB1]

As you can see, the tags stay the same for their respective index rows, instead of changing to what it should be- their filtered index rows.

Here is my code- the way I programmed it is kind of through a loophole (storing data in a hidden label in the `UITableViewCell`), so that could be the source of the problem, although I'm not sure.

On `mainViewController`:

```
class SearchViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UISearchBarDelegate {

     var items: [ItemsModel] = []
     var filteredItems: [ItemsModel] = []
     var searching = false
     var delegate: controlsReloadingCollectionView?

     public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell
        var tags = ""
        if searching {
            cell.nameLabel.text = filteredItems[indexPath.row].name
            cell.infoLabel.text = "## mi  \u{2022}  \(filteredItems[indexPath.row].Age ?? "") age  \u{2022}  \(filteredItems[indexPath.row].StartTime ?? "") "
            
            tags = filteredItems[indexPath.row].Tags!
            cell.tagsModelLabel.text = tags
        }
        else {
            cell.nameLabel.text = items[indexPath.row].name
            cell.infoLabel.text = "## mi  \u{2022}  \(Items[indexPath.row].Age ?? "") age  \u{2022}  \(Items[indexPath.row].StartTime ?? "") "
            tags = items[indexPath.row].Tags!
            cell.tagsModelLabel.text = tags                   
        }
        return cell
    }
    
  func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
   
       filteredItems = items.filter({ItemsModel -> Bool in
           guard let text = searchBar.text else { return false }
        return itemsModel.itemName!.lowercased().contains(text.lowercased())
       })
        searching = true
        SearchItemListTableView.reloadData()
        self.delegate?.reloadCollectionView()   
    }

}
```

On TableViewCell:

```
protocol controlsReloadingCollectionView {
    func reloadCollectionView()
} // I used this so I could call this function in the mainViewController.

class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, controlsReloadingCollectionView {


      @IBOutlet var itemNameLabel: UILabel!
      @IBOutlet weak var infoLabel: UILabel!
      @IBOutlet weak var TagsCollectionView: UICollectionView!
      var tagsCollectionViewArray = [String]()

     override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        
        TagsCollectionView.delegate = self
        TagsCollectionView.dataSource = self
        TagsCollectionView.reloadData()  
    }

 func reloadCollectionView() {
        TagsCollectionView.reloadData()
    }

    func setTagsCollectionViewArray() {
            tagsCollectionViewArray = tagsModelLabel.text?.components(separatedBy: " ") ?? ["didn't work"]
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        
        if tagsModelLabel.text == "" {
            return 0
        }
        else {
            setTagsCollectionViewArray()
            return tagsCollectionViewArray.count
        }  
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "SearchTagsCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! TagsCollectionViewCell
     
        setTagsCollectionViewArray()
        cell.tagsLabel.text = tagsCollectionViewArray[indexPath.row] 
        cell.tagsLabel.sizeToFit()
        return cell
    }
    
}
```

Does anyone know why it's not working? I've tried different things such as assigning different variables and a different hidden label for filtered items, but nothing seems to have worked for me. When I run the code, the hidden label actually shows up correctly when I search, though, it's just I can't get any variable on the `TableViewCell` side to update properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply make like below:

**On mainViewController:**

```
 var items: [ItemsModel] = []
 var filteredItems: [ItemsModel] = []
 var searching = false
 var delegate: controlsReloadingCollectionView?

 public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell
    var tags = ""
    if searching {
        cell.nameLabel.text = filteredItems[indexPath.row].name
        cell.infoLabel.text = "## mi  \u{2022}  \(filteredItems[indexPath.row].Age ?? "") age  \u{2022}  \(filteredItems[indexPath.row].StartTime ?? "") "
        
        tags = filteredItems[indexPath.row].Tags!
        cell.tagsModelLabel.text = tags
        cell.tagsCollectionViewArray = yourDataSourceArray //Array which you want to display in collectionView
         
    } else {
        cell.nameLabel.text = items[indexPath.row].name
        cell.infoLabel.text = "## mi  \u{2022}  \(Items[indexPath.row].Age ?? "") age  \u{2022}  \(Items[indexPath.row].StartTime ?? "") "
        tags = items[indexPath.row].Tags!
        cell.tagsModelLabel.text = tags
        cell.tagsCollectionViewArray = yourDataSourceArray //Array which you want to display in collectionView                   
    }
    
    cell.yourCollectionView.reloadData() //Reload your collectionView
    return cell
}
```

After calling your API(if you use) simply reload your tableView in success result of API with

> yourTable.reloadData()

it's working like charm.